# php - sort array by custom criteria

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects:

```
object1->
name="Name1"
key="key1"

object2->
name="Name2"
key="key2"

object3->
name="Name3"
key="key3"
```

and an array of priority keys:

```
$keys = ["key3", "key1"];
```

I need to sort the array of objects based on priority keys, so the result should be:

```
object3:
name="Name3"
key="key3"

object1->
name="Name1"
key="key1"

object2:
name="Name2"
key="key2"
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: i edited the answer to prioritize only the keys added in the array and leave the rest below them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to add a priority as integer, and sort the array from the highest integer to the lowest using `usort()`

for example you have this data

```
 <?php

 $data = [];

 $data[0] = new stdClass;
 $data[0]->name = "name1";
 $data[0]->key = 'key1';

 $data[1] = new stdClass;
 $data[1]->name = "name2";
 $data[1]->key = 'key2';

 $data[2] = new stdClass;
 $data[2]->name = "name3";
 $data[2]->key = 'key3';


 $keys = ["key3", "key1"];
```

you can sort it this way

```
function sortByPriority($data , $keys){
    $priority = array();
    $i = count($keys);
    foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
      $i--;
      $priority[$value] = $i;
    }
    usort($data, function($a, $b) use($priority){
      $a = isset($priority[$a->key]) ? $priority[$a->key] : -1;
      $b = isset($priority[$b->key]) ? $priority[$b->key] : -1;
      return $b - $a;
    });

    return $data;
 }


 var_dump(sortByPriority($data, $keys));
```

sample output

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'name' => string 'name3' (length=5)
      public 'key' => string 'key3' (length=4)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'name' => string 'name1' (length=5)
      public 'key' => string 'key1' (length=4)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'name' => string 'name2' (length=5)
      public 'key' => string 'key2' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you prepare your priority lookup array it is merely a matter of passing it into `usort()`'s scope and either using the related priority value or if the `key` property's value is not in the priority array, then use the fallback value.  Readable, direct, and concise.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pFaHH))

```
$objects = [
   (object)["name" => "Name1", "key" => "key1"],
   (object)["name" => "Name2", "key" => "key2"],
   (object)["name" => "Name3", "key" => "key3"],
];

$keys = ["key3", "key1"];
$lookup = array_flip($keys);
$fallback = count($keys);

usort($objects, function($a, $b) use ($lookup, $fallback) {
    return ($lookup[$a->key] ?? $fallback) <=> ($lookup[$b->key] ?? $fallback);
});

var_export($objects);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'name' => 'Name3',
     'key' => 'key3',
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'name' => 'Name1',
     'key' => 'key1',
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'name' => 'Name2',
     'key' => 'key2',
  ),
)
```

---

From PHP7.4, the syntax can be further condensed and the `use()` declaration omitted. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7N1iN))

```
usort($objects, fn($a, $b) => ($lookup[$a->key] ?? $fallback) <=> ($lookup[$b->key] ?? $fallback));
```

Answer (score -1):

There is the function [usort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php) in PHP do what you need :

```
usort( $your_array), "sort_function");
sort_function( $a, $b) {
   // your sort logic
}
```

Comment: how do I involve two arrays in sorting? It is basically sorting of an array depending on values in another array

Comment: What is the priority logic in your second array ?

Comment: there is no logic, priorities come from another source and I should sort an array based on that