# php sort 2d array by sort order of another 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, custom-sort

I have two multi-dimensional arrays and need to sort the first array in the same order as the second array based on different keys (but their values are the same).  In the below example I need `$allOptions` to be sorted into the same order as `$regOptions` but based on the values of `clID == optID`.

However, not all `$allOptions` sub-arrays (clID) are present in `$regOptions` sub-arrays (optID)....so any non-matched elements in `$allOptions` would be thrown to the bottom/end of the array.

How can I do this?

```
$allOptions = array(
     array("clID"=> 171, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 191, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 131, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 101, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 201, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 181, ...other values),
     ...
     array("clID"=> 99, ...other values),  // not in regOptions
     array("clID"=> 129, ...other values)  // not in regOptions
     array("clID"=> 139, ...other values)
    
) ;

$regOptions = array(
    array("order"=>1,"optID"=> 131, ...other values),
    array("order"=>2,"optID"=> 191, ...other values),
    array("order"=>3,"optID"=> 181, ...other values),
    array("order"=>4,"optID"=> 139, ...other values),
    array("order"=>5,"optID"=> 101, ...other values),
    array("order"=>6,"optID"=> 201, ...other values),
    array("order"=>7,"optID"=> 171, ...other values) 
    ...
) ;
```

So the output would be:

```
$allOptions = array(
     array("clID"=> 131, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 191, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 181, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 139, ...other values)
     array("clID"=> 101, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 201, ...other values),
     array("clID"=> 171, ...other values),
     ...
     array("clID"=> 99, ...other values),  // not in regOptions
     array("clID"=> 129, ...other values)  // not in regOptions
) ;
```

Comment: [PHP sort array by priority](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50511018/2943403) and [PHP How to sort an array of objects based on priority order with a backup of alphabetical?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21068047/2943403) and [Sort array of arrays by a column with custom sorting priority (not alphabetically)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23352157/2943403) and [php - sort array by custom criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27431754/2943403) and [Sorting 2-D associative array and categorizing on basis of a key value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16159601/2943403)

Comment: and [PHP make some of the Key to be sticky in an Associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56230671/2943403) and [Sort an array of numbers by another predefined, non-exhaustive array of number, then sort ascending](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53910767/2943403) and [Sort array of strings by 3rd-to-last character based on another array then sort on whole strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40816754/2943403) and [usort multisort array based on another array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25603313/2943403)

Comment: and [How to implement multiple custom sorting rules based on hyphen-delimited substrings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8447281/2943403) and [Custom sort an associative array by its keys using a lookup array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40868637/2943403) and [Custom sort a multidimensional array by subarray keys using another array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54208632/2943403)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All earlier posted answers are working Waaaaaaaay too hard.  Use `array_column()` to generate a lookup array.  Use `usort()` or `array_multisort()` to sort by that priority array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/abW9q))

```
$priority = array_column($regOptions, 'order', 'optID');
usort(
    $allOptions,
    fn($a, $b) => ($priority[$a['clID']] ?? PHP_INT_MAX) <=> ($priority[$b['clID']] ?? PHP_INT_MAX)
);
var_export($allOptions);
```

If you want to fallback to sorting by clID ASC for all of the unmentioned clId values, then use the elvis operator to break those ties with a simple 3-way comparison on the column value.

```
$priority = array_column($regOptions, 'order', 'optID');
usort(
    $allOptions,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        ($priority[$a['clID']] ?? PHP_INT_MAX) <=> ($priority[$b['clID']] ?? PHP_INT_MAX)
        ?: $a['clID'] <=> $b['clID']
);
```

The first script can be performed with `array_multisort()` in the following way. Note that this approach may perform better than `usort()` because it makes fewer lookups, but it does sort on `$priority`, then sort on `$allOptions` row length, then `clId` (how it would work if you called `sort($allOptions)`; I imagine that the rows all have the same length though). ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/URhoB))

```
$priority = array_column($regOptions, 'order', 'optID');
array_multisort(
    array_map(fn($v) => $priority[$v['clID']] ?? PHP_INT_MAX, $allOptions),
    $allOptions
);
var_export($allOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and input on all the responses here.  very informative.  Yet your solution above (1st one) is generating this error: `unexpected '=> (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)', expecting ')'` on this section of code `fn($a, $b) => `

Comment: As you can see from my runnable demo links, these scripts are correct and modern.  Are you using a version of PHP below PHP7.4?

Comment: ah...yes, the server is pinned to 7.3....server upgrade is beyond my control.

Comment: In that case, you cannot yet enjoy "arrow function" syntax.  Must be: `usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return $a <=> $b; });`

Answer (score 0):

Use php usort()

Example

```
    function customSort($a, $b, $regOptions) {
      $aOptID = $a['clID'];
      $bOptID = $b['clID'];
      $aOrder = array_search($aOptID, array_column($regOptions, 'optID'));
      $bOrder = array_search($bOptID, array_column($regOptions, 'optID'));

      if ($aOrder === false) $aOrder = PHP_INT_MAX;

      if ($bOrder === false) $bOrder = PHP_INT_MAX;

      return $aOrder - $bOrder;
    } 

    usort($allOptions, function($a, $b) use ($regOptions) {
      return customSort($a, $b, $regOptions);
    });
```

Comment: @rolinger I edited the code; when I read it, either it wasn't in there or it escaped my attention that the arrays might not match

Comment: @rolinger I do not encourage you to use this unexplained answer, it is making performing multiple cycles over the data on each iteration of `usort()`.  Not only is this script verbose, it is not going to be the best performing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution not based on `array_search()`:

```
$allOptions = [["clID" => 1], ["clID" => 2], ["clID" => 3], ["clID" => 4]];
$regOptions = [["optID" => 3], ["optID" => 2]];

$order = [];
foreach($regOptions as $key => $option)
    $order[$option['optID']] = $key;

usort($allOptions, function($o1, $o2) use($order)
{
    $id1 = $o1['clID'];
    $id2 = $o2['clID'];
    if(isset($order[$id1]) && isset($order[$id2]))
        return $order[$id1] <=> $order[$id2];
    if(isset($order[$id1]) && !isset($order[$id2]))
        return -1;
    if(!isset($order[$id1]) && isset($order[$id2]))
        return 1;
    return $id1 <=> $id2;
});

var_export($allOptions);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'clID' => 3,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'clID' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'clID' => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'clID' => 4,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Please see my educational links under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to sorting would be iterating over `$regOptions` and building a new array from `$indexedOptions`, and then appending any items not found to the end. Live example at https://3v4l.org/jd5Rq

```
<?php

$allOptions = array(
    array("clID"=> 171),
    array("clID"=> 191),
    array("clID"=> 131),
    array("clID"=> 101),
    array("clID"=> 201),
    array("clID"=> 181),
    array("clID"=> 99),  // not in regOptions
    array("clID"=> 129),  // not in regOptions
    array("clID"=> 139),
) ;

$regOptions = array(
    array("order"=>1,"optID"=> 131),
    array("order"=>2,"optID"=> 191),
    array("order"=>3,"optID"=> 181),
    array("order"=>4,"optID"=> 139),
    array("order"=>5,"optID"=> 101),
    array("order"=>6,"optID"=> 201),
    array("order"=>7,"optID"=> 171) 
);

// build new array from original array with indexes for faster lookups
$indexedOptions = [];
foreach($allOptions as $val) {
    $indexedOptions[$val['clID']] = $val;
}

$newArray = [];
foreach ($regOptions as $order) {
    $id = $order['optID'];
    
    if (isset($indexedOptions[$id])) {
        $newArray[] = $indexedOptions[$id];
        unset($indexedOptions[$id]);
    }
}

// at this point, $newArray has all of the found values in order,
// and $indexedOptions has any remaining items.
// var_dump($newArray);
// var_dump($indexedOptions);

// put them together for the final array
$final = array_merge($newArray, $indexedOptions);

var_dump($final);
```

Output:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=> array(1) {
    ["clID"]=> int(131) 
  }
  [1]=> array(1) {
    ["clID"]=> int(191) 
  }
  [2]=> array(1) {
    ["clID"]=> int(181) 
  }
  [3]=> array(1) {
    ["clID"]=> int(139) 
  }
  [4]=> array(1) {
    ["clID"]=> int(101) 
  }
  [5]=> array(1) {
    ["clID"]=> int(201) 
  }
  [6]=> array(1) {
    ["clID"]=> int(171) 
  }
  [7]=> array(1) {
    ["clID"]=> int(99) 
  }
  [8]=> array(1) {
    ["clID"]=> int(129) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: This brute force script that merges the whitelisted values with the whole input array doesn't seem very elegant to me.  For each value not mentioned in the lookup array, there will be N number of fruitless cycles.

Comment: Agreed, and it could easily be improved by first indexing the array by `clID` for faster lookups. But other early answers were missing the "add missing items to the end of the array" and I wanted to offer an alternate solution.